# Find object A and number of objects B has pointer with object A in a query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a big question and need your help. It's about parse SDK.

I have 2 class named A and B.
B has a column named author is a pointer to A.

My question: In query find object A, I want to get number of B object has pointer to A. If cannot get in a query, can you suggest me solution to do my task with minimum request to parse?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("B");
query.whereEqualTo("pointertoA", ObjectA );
query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
 public void done(int count, ParseException e) {{
    if (e == null) {
        // "use count
    } else {
        // Something went wrong...
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thank but i want to get list A and number of object B linked with every object A.

Comment: Use each loop available in parse and run above query in it.

Comment: If list object with large size, we have to sent many request to count B. Any solution? Bro.

Comment: parse.each doesnot have a upper limit. Source:- https://parse.com/questions/paging-through-more-than-10000-results